# When you need me, you throw me away. When you don't need me, you take me back

Tags: riddle

This is a simple one... Maybe you can solve it.

What am I:

> When you need me, you throw me away.
>
> When you don't need me, you take me back.

Please identify me.

Comment: ... and ***that*** question is closed as too broad.

Answer (score 5):

Is the item in question

> an [anchor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor)?

Comment: Could you add spoiler tags (the characters >! before any line you want to hide) so others don't see the answer before they have a chance to try for themselves?

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a

> Fishing net or a fishing rod which you throw in order to catch the fish and get it back when you don't need it

Comment: The 2nd item I agree, I never tossed the 1st when I need it though ;)

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> A boomerang, when used as hunting equipment, comes back by itself, but you'd still take it back when the hunting's done.

Or for that matter

> Any other item thrown away by athletes or for hunting purposes like javelins, discs and balls